# jdom2 Encoding Problem in XML UTF-8 Output

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, fileoutputstream, jdom-2

I try to update some attribute values an existing XML file using jdom2. I'm getting the utf8 encoding problem when I create the xml file.

The attribute value is `"1 student Noun".`

But the value I see in the output is :

```
1&#x9;student&#x9;Noun
```

The code I have written is shown below:

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
            Document document = document = builder.build(filePath);

            Element root = document.getRootElement();

            for(Element sentenceElement : root.getChildren("sentence")){

                String transcriptionText = "";

                 for(Element transcriptionElement : sentenceElement.getChildren("transcription")){

                     for(Element wordElement : transcriptionElement.getChildren("word")){
                            transcriptionText += " "+wordElement.getAttributeValue("text");
                     } 

                     transcriptionParser = ParserUtil.getResponse(transcriptionText);
                     transcriptionElement.getAttribute("text").setValue(transcriptionText);
                     transcriptionElement.getAttribute("parser").setValue(transcriptionParser);
                 }

                 for(Element translationElement : sentenceElement.getChildren("translation")){

                        translationParser = getResponse(translationElement.getAttributeValue("text"));
                        translationElement.getAttribute("parser").setValue(translationParser);

                 }
            }

            Format format = Format.getPrettyFormat();

            XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter(format);


            /*try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
               xmlOutput.output(document, out);
              }catch(Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }*/

            xmlOutput.output(document, Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filePath),StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

I have used both of the options:

```
xmlOutput.output(document, Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filePath),StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

and

```
    try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
         xmlOutput.output(document, out);
   }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

But none of them have been solved the problem. How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The string `"1 student Noun"` obviously contains tab characters between the words.

So if the XML output contains `1&#x9;student&#x9;Noun` thats' perfectly ok. The tab characters has the Unicode value 9 and `&#x9;` is a proper XML entity to represent that.

Comment: And note, this is nothing to do with UTF-8 or encoding. If you want spaces rather than tabs in the string, you need to modify the string before creating the attribute node in the XML.